# How to change a sprite image in python based on mouse direction

Tags: python, sprite

I've seen several different posts about changing a sprite image.
For the current assignment, I have to construct a packman sprite, then it should follow the mouse. No problem there.
Here is that bit of code:

```
class Packman(games.Sprite):
    """Create the packman that is conrolled by the mouse"""
    #load the packman image
    image_right = games.load_image("snap_right.png") # initial value
    image_left = games.load_image("snap_left.png")
    show_image = image_right



    def __init__(self, x=games.mouse.x, y = games.mouse.y):
        """Initialise packman"""
        super(Packman, self).__init__(image = Packman.show_image, x = games.mouse.x, y = games.mouse.y)

    def update(self):
        """Move packmans coordinates"""
        self.x = games.mouse.x
        self.y = games.mouse.y

        if self.left < 0:
            self.left = 0

        if self.right > games.screen.width:
            self.right = games.screen.width

        #change Packman's direction that he is facing`
```

As you can see I try and load two images, but only one image at a time will be displayed.
(I reckon there is a way of just flipping one image horizontally, in stead of using two images.) As is, I can move Packman around. Now I need to add the bit that makes Packman face left/right depending on the direction the mouse is traveling in. My handbook gives me an example to rotate the image through 180deg with keypresses, which work, but then packman is just upside down, with his eye at the bottom.

Is there another way of flipping packman depending on mouse direction? (I only need horizontal flip, i.e. left and right)

Answer (score 1):

Well I use Pygame for my sprites but the solution is pretty simple.

I basically use something like this. Two pointers pointing to initialized images. And then a pointer to pointers called `image` which will be what we use to draw the sprites.

```
# image is the pointer that points to the pointer that points to the image being currently used
image1 = pygame.image.load('left.png')
image2 = pygame.image.load('right.png')
image = image1
```

Then in draw I just do

```
screen.blit(image, position)
```

Now since you are using the mouse to track the position of pacman. What you have to do is this. At EACH frame, store the location of the mouse x and y in a class variable. Call it something like `old_x` and `old_y`. On the next frame, simply compare your mouse x position to your `old_x`. If the mouse position is greater, your pacman is trying to move to the right. `image = image2` If your mouse position is less, then your pacman is moving to the left. `image = image1` Apply the necessary state changes and change your image accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the info. We are using livewires for animation. The pygame solutions is the only ones I can find, but was unable to figure it out. I will try again and report back.

Comment: same concept though, the idea of comparing "old value" to "new value" is what hes trying to point out.

Comment: Ah cool. But the basic concept should be the same, right? You have frames and at each frame, you update the display surface by redrawing it?